# How to run a php function in background separate from the main thread?

Tags: php, exec

So I have a main php thread in which I want to call a function such that it runs in the background and doesn`t keep the user waiting since this function takes a long time to execute.

```
$logFile = 'app-output.txt';
$command = 'nohup /export/php -r "require \'/export/wiki.php\';update_wiki(1);" &';
$command.= ' > "'.$logFile.'" 2>&1';
exec($command);
```

So I tried doing it using exec function but for some reason it doesn`t run in the background. 
WHere wiki.php is the file having an update_wiki function that takes a long time so I want to redirect the user back to the page he came from while this fucntion does its job as it is anyways indepedent and dumps the output somewhere else

Comment: `exec` does not run in background, you need [pcntl-fork.php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-fork.php)

Comment: Can you elaborate how can I run this update_wiki() using pcntl-fork?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here is sample approach with fork:

```
$logFile = 'app-output.txt';
$command = 'nohup /export/php -r "require \'/export/wiki.php\';update_wiki(1);" &';
$command.= ' > "'.$logFile.'" 2>&1';

$pid = pcntl_fork();
if ($pid == -1) {
     die('could not fork');
} else if ($pid) {
     // we are the parent, do nothing
} else {
     // we are the child
    exec($command);
}
```

a little bit another approach can be:

```
$pid = pcntl_fork();
if ($pid == -1) {
     die('could not fork');
} else if ($pid) {
     // we are the parent, do nothing
} else {
     // we are the child
    $logFile = 'app-output.txt';
    ob_start();
    require '/export/wiki.php';
    update_wiki(1);

    file_put_contents($logFile, ob_get_contents());
}
```

Comment: Does the child process automatically die after it has finished executing?

Comment: @user2601010 yes, as soon as script is finished - it will die

Comment: And are there any shortcomings or things to watch out for with this approach?

Comment: @user2601010 usually - no, the only problem I see with 2nd one - if something goes wrong in php code - log file will not be saved, so it makes sense to enable php error logging and log errors inside php code instead of console output

Answer (score 2):

I think the issue is that your ampersand is not quite in the right place. Try this:

```
$logFile = 'app-output.txt';
$command = '(nohup /export/php -r "require \'/export/wiki.php\';update_wiki(1);"';
$command.= ' > "'.$logFile.'" 2>&1) &';
exec($command);
```